# RecordEditForm problem with Picklist value code has no syntactical error

Tags: lightning, community

I am Trying to auto-populate the picklist value of language field in New Quote page from account language field.
But its not working. I am able to do same for lookup-fields.`

```
<aura:component controller="LexQuoteCtrl"            implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="quote_data" type="LexQuoteCtrl" />
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notificationsLibrary"/>
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="newRecordForm"  objectApiName="EncQuote__c"
                              onload="{!c.new_rec}"
                              onsubmit="{!c.save_record}"
                              onsuccess="{!c.invoke}">
                <lightning:messages/>
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning:button label="Save" type="submit" variant="success"/>
                </div>
                <lightning:card title="Quote Information">
                    <!--
                        Divided the lighting card into two columns
                    -->
                   <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                       <div class="slds-col">
                           <span>
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" aura:id="quotename"/>
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountName__c" value="{!v.quote_data.acc_name}" disabled="true"/>
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity_Name__c" value="{!v.quote_data.opp_name}" disabled="true"/>
                <!-- Lightning formatted Address also we can use-->
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="QuoteTo__c" value="{!v.quote_data.address}" disabled="true" />
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Contact__c" value="{!v.quote_data.con_name}"/>
                           </span>
                   </div>

                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Language__c" aura:id="quoteLanguage" value="{!v.quote_data.accountLanguage}"/>
                            {!v.language}
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Reference__c" aura:id="quotereference"/>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Review_Manager__c" aura:id="reviewManager" />
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Zahlungsbedingungen__c" aura:id="termsOfPayment" value="{!v.quote_data.termsOfPayment}"/>
                            <!--

                            <lightning:inputField  fieldName="SAPZahlungsbedingungen__c" value="{!v.quote_data.termsOfPayment}"/>

                            <lightning:inputField  fieldName="SAPLieferbedingungen__c" value="{!v.quote_data.deliveryTerms}"/>
                            -->
                        </div>
                       </div>
`
```

JS Controller

```
new_rec : function (component, event, helper){
        var opptyId= component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(opptyId);
        var action = component.get("c.getLexQuoteCtrl");
        action.setParams({"opptyId": opptyId});
        console.log('new_rec');
        action.setCallback(this, function(responce){
            var state = responce.getState();
            if(state==='SUCCESS'){
                console.log(state);
                var result = responce.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.quote_data",result);
                var lan= component.get("v.quote_data.accountLanguage");
                component.find("reviewManager").set("v.value",component.get("v.quote_data.reviewManager"));
                component.set("v.language",lan);
}
else{
                console.log('ERROR IN RESPONCE '+state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
save_record : function(component, event, helper) {
event.preventDefault();
        //all field 
        var fields = event.getParams("fields");
        var quote_data = component.get("v.quote_data");
fields["Name"] = component.find("quotename").get("v.value");

        fields["Quote_Language__c"] = component.find("quoteLanguage").get("v.value");
        fields["Contact__c"] = quote_data.con_name  ;
        fields["Opportunity__c"] = quote_data.opportunityId ;
            console.log('save_record: '+error,result);
            if (result && result.id)
            {
                component.set('v.quoteid', result.id);
            }

        }, function(f){


            console.log(f);



        });
    },
        invoke : function(component, event, helper) {


             var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            var quoteid = component.get('v.quoteid');
            navEvt.setParams({
              "recordId": quoteid
            });
            navEvt.fire();
        },
})
```

Apex controller

```
public class LexQuoteCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public string opp_name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string acc_name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string con_name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string sap_number{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string address{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string termsOfPayment{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string deliveryTerms{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string accountLanguage{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string opportunityId;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string shippingTerms{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string reviewManager{get;set;}

@AuraEnabled
    public static LexQuoteCtrl getLexQuoteCtrl(string opptyId){
        LexQuoteCtrl lexObj = new LexQuoteCtrl();
        lexObj.opportunityId=opptyId;
        //lexObj.quoteId = (String)stdController.getRecord().get(EncQuote__c.Id.getDescribe().getName());
        opportunity oppty= [select id,name,accountid,OwnerId,
                            Account.Id,Account.name,Account.SAP_Kontaktsprache__c,Account.SapKundenummer__c,Account.Versandbedingungen__c,Account.BillingStreet,Account.BillingCity,Account.BillingCountry,Account.Zahlungsbedingungen__c,Account.Lieferbedingungen__c 
                            from opportunity where id=:opptyId];
        contact con = [select id,name from contact where accountId=:oppty.AccountId limit 1];
        Review_Manager__c rm =[SELECT quoteOwner__c,ReviewManager__c FROM Review_Manager__c where quoteOwner__c=:oppty.OwnerId];

        //Account acc=[select id, name from account where id=:oppty.accountid];
        lexObj.opp_name= oppty.name;
        lexObj.acc_name= oppty.Account.name;
        lexObj.con_name=con.id;
        lexObj.reviewManager=rm.ReviewManager__c;
        lexObj.sap_number=oppty.Account.SapKundenummer__c;
        lexObj.address= oppty.Account.BillingStreet+' - '+oppty.Account.BillingCity+', '+oppty.Account.BillingCountry;
        lexObj.termsOfPayment=oppty.Account.Zahlungsbedingungen__c;
        lexObj.deliveryTerms=oppty.Account.Lieferbedingungen__c;
        lexObj.shippingTerms=oppty.Account.Versandbedingungen__c;
        if (oppty.Account.SAP_Kontaktsprache__c != 'DE'){

                lexObj.accountLanguage= 'EN'; 
        } else{
                lexObj.accountLanguage= 'DE';
        }
        return lexObj;
    }
    //testing option from Schema
  public  List<String> getselectOptions() {
  List<String> options = new List<String>();
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.SAP_Kontaktsprache__c.getDescribe();
      List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
      for(Schema.PicklistEntry p: ple){
          options.add(p.getLabel());
      }
      return options;
  }
}
//:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should bind your language value to an attribute:

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Language__c" aura:id="quoteLanguage" value="{!v.language}"/>
```

Second: your javascript code should be more organized, and should set this attribute:

```
new_rec : function (component, event, helper){
    var opptyId= component.get("v.recordId");
    console.log(opptyId);
    var action = component.get("c.getLexQuoteCtrl");
    action.setParams({"opptyId": opptyId});
    console.log('new_rec');
    action.setCallback(this, function(responce){
        var state = responce.getState();
        if(state==='SUCCESS'){
            console.log(state);
            var result = responce.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.quote_data",result);
            component.set("v.language", result.accountLanguage);
        }
        else{
            console.log('ERROR IN RESPONCE '+state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

If you have more trouble than that, please specify exactly where in the code and what do you see in the log

Comment: Thanks a lot.....its resolved now and it worked when I removed the value from inputfield and directly set the value in JS controller